# how can I change the color of a table based on selected drop down item using php ajax javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am fairly new to php and even newer to PDO! what I am trying to do is change the color of the row based on selection of a drop down in my form, but I do not have a clue how to do this!

I have only been googling around for a bit about this, have not found anything that is close to what I am trying to do

here is the main table

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <label>Current Status
        <select name="current_status">
            <option>Select Status</option>
            <?php foreach($statuses as $key => $value) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option> 
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
      </label>
```

here is the "key" code

```
'InProgress'=>'In Progress',
'Completed'=>'Completed',
'Unstatused'=>'Unstatused'
```

here is the contoroller page code

```
  <div class="large-4 columns">
      <label>Select Current Status
          <select name="current_status">
            <?php foreach($statuses as $key => $value) : ?>
                <?php 
                    if($key == $task->current_status) {
                        $selected ='selected';
                    }else{
                        $selected='';
                    }
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $value; ?></option> 
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>

     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $task->id; ?>">
     <input name="submit" type="submit" class="add_btn button right small" value="submit"> 
     <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</form>
</div>
```

so what I am hoping can be done here is;
if "completed" was selected in the forms dropdown - then I want to change the row color that holds that task to red, and if they select "unstatused" i want to have that table row change to blue..but i do not have a clue as to how to do this!

```
    <table><!--start table-->
            <thead><!--create the headers-->
                <tr><!--the table row for the table headers-->
                    <th width="100">task date</th>
                    <th width="450">task title</th>
                    <th width="150">assigned to</th>
                    <th width="100">current status</th>
                    <th width="200">action</th>
                </tr><!--close the table header table row-->
             </thead><!--close the headers-->
                <tbody><!--begin the table body-->
                <?php foreach($tasks as $task) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $task->task_date; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $task->task_title; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $task->assigned_to; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $task->current_status; ?></td>

                       <td>
                        <ul class="button-group radius">
<li>
<a href="#" class="button tiny" data-reveal-id="editModal<?php echo $task->id; ?>" data-task-id="<?php echo $task->id; ?>">Edit</a>
<div id= "editModal<?php echo $task->id; ?>" data-cid= "<?php echo $task->id; ?>"  class="reveal-modal editModal" data-reveal>
```

the row I want to change is the "current_status" row - based on if they selected "completed" or "In Progress" in the form that is used to populate the table.

JEFF- here is the full code page (the controller page)

```
<?php
//create database object
$db = new Database;
//bring in the contacts
$db->query("SELECT * FROM multytasklist");
//assign the resultset
$tasks = $db->resultset();
?>

 <div class="row"><!--begin the row for table data-->
    <div class="large-12 columns"><!--begin columns-->
        <table><!--start table-->
            <thead><!--create the headers-->
                <tr><!--the table row for the table headers-->
                    <th width="100">task date</th>
                    <th width="450">task title</th>
                    <th width="150">assigned to</th>
                    <th width="100">current status</th>
                    <th width="200">action</th>
                </tr><!--close the table header table row-->
             </thead><!--close the headers-->
                <tbody><!--begin the table body-->
                <?php foreach($tasks as $task) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $task->task_date; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $task->task_title; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $task->assigned_to; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $task->current_status; ?></td>

                       <td>
                        <ul class="button-group radius">
<li>
<a href="#" class="button tiny" data-reveal-id="editModal<?php echo $task->id; ?>" data-task-id="<?php echo $task->id; ?>">Edit</a>
<div id= "editModal<?php echo $task->id; ?>" data-cid= "<?php echo $task->id; ?>"  class="reveal-modal editModal" data-reveal>

    <h2>EDIT TASK</h2>

   <form id="edit_multytask" action="#" method="POST">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <label>Task Date
        <input name="task_date" type="text" placeholder="task date.." value="<?php echo $task->task_date; ?>">
      </label>
    </div>

     <div class="large-6 columns">
      <label>Task Title
        <input name="task_title" type="text" placeholder="task title.." value="<?php echo $task->task_title; ?>" >
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <label>Task Description
        <input name="task_description" type="text" placeholder="task description.." value="<?php echo $task->task_description; ?>" >
      </label>
    </div>
    </div>


     <div class="row">
     <div class="large-12 columns">
      <label>assigned to
        <input name="assigned_to" type="text" placeholder="assigned to.." value="<?php echo $task->assigned_to; ?>" >
      </label>
     </div>
     </div> 


   <div class="large-4 columns">
      <label>Select Current Status
          <select name="current_status">
            <?php foreach($statuses as $key => $value) : ?>
                <?php 
                    if($key == $task->current_status) {
                        $selected ='selected';
                    }else{
                        $selected='';
                    }
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $value; ?></option> 
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>

     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $task->id; ?>">
     <input name="submit" type="submit" class="add_btn button right small" value="submit"> 
     <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</form>
</div>
</li>

<li>
    <form id="delete_multytask" action="#" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $task->id; ?>">
        <input type="submit" class="delete_btn button tiny secondary alert" value="delete">
    </form>
</li>
                        </ul><!--close unordered list-->

                       </td><!--close table data-->
                    </tr><!--close table row-->
                   <?php endforeach; ?>
                 </tbody><!--close tbody-->
             </table><!--close table-->
         </div><!--close 12 column class-->
        </div><!--close row-->
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are wanting. If you want the colour to change when you select on option then you will need javascript to add the appropriate css class to the item. If you are wanting to show an item with a particular colour then you are need to set the css class for the item within the controller.

Comment: so what I am hoping can be done here is;
if "completed" was selected in the forms dropdown - then I want to change the row color that holds that task to red, and if they select "unstatused" i want to have that table row change to blue..but i do not have a clue as to how to do this!

Comment: Where is your table? Which row?

Comment: sorry Dharman - I edited the original post to include the table (well, most of it anyways!) - and not to keep repeating myself - but this is what I want; if a user selects "completed" (this is the "current_status" datatable column) if they select "completed" in the form - then I would like to have that row that they are on to change to a red color, or if they have selected "in progress" in the form for "current status" then I want the row they are affecting to change to a yellow color

Answer (score 1):

This is happening dynamically so php and pdo are inappropriate in this situation.
Your css needs to be:

```
<style>
.InProgress { background-color: red; }
.Completed { background-color: orange; }
.Unstatused { background-color: blue; }
</style>
```

You need to change the `<select>` item to:

```
<select name="current_status" onchange='changeColors(this.value)'>
```

Add some JavaScript:

```
<script>
function changeColors( value ) {
  var element = document.getElementById('myElementToChange');
  element.className = value;
}
```

Please note that this is a rough guideline as you have not provided the full html so I can only guess at what you want to change.

Comment: hi Jeff and thank you for your help - I am new here and am trying to figure out how this site formats questions and stuffs so forgive me if It all seems so chaotic! I have just posted the controller page form for you to look at - because I do understand information is limited! I did try what you said (adding to css3 and js) but alas it laughed at me and gave me the golden boot LOLL

Comment: the "current_status" is a drop down field in my form and it holds 3 values(completed, in progress, and unstatused) when a user selects a row in the table - and then clicks the edit button, - the form will open and allow them to change information(such as changing the "current_status" form field from "in progress" to "completed") - and in turn, after hitting the form submit button..the row in the table should show a color based on the status they selected in the form..*wow, thats a lot of typing!*